# What does the equivalence to this Python list look like in Java?

Tags: java, python, translate

I'm trying to learn Java, more specifically I'm trying to learn a couple of differences when working with arrays and lists. Right now I'm trying to understand how I can implement this line `list += [i]*i`  in Java.

```
Sum = 5000
list = [0, 0]
x = 1
while len(list) < Sum:
    list += [x]*x
    x += 1
```

I've tried a lot of different methods but I can't seem to find a way. The results I get in Java with the methods I've tried are all wrong.

Comment: To make this a useful question (see the SO [help]) you should include that Java code that you wrote and indicate exactly what goes wrong; that may be useful for future readers. Right now your question boils down to asking others to write code for you which is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly translated (with the helpful utility function `java.util.Collections.nCopies`) it becomes something like:

```
import java.util.*;

int Sum = 5000;  //Following the naming convention in Java (and Python) "Sum" should be lowercase

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//Alternatively: List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list.add(0);
list.add(0);

int x = 1;
while (list.size() < Sum) {
    list.addAll(Collections.nCopies(x, x));
    x += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of for loop, add method and a ArrayList data structure. It could look something like below.

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
int x = 1;
while (condition){
  for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
    nums.add(x);
  }
  x+=1
}
```